# Authorize Azure API connection through powershell using an SPN

Tags: azure, powershell, api, azure-logic-apps, service-principal

I'm trying to authorize an Azure API connection through powershell.
However i've ran into an issue when i'm trying to do so, using an SPN.

I taken inspiration from
https://github.com/logicappsio/LogicAppConnectionAuth

Which uses the Invoke-AzResoureAction "listconsentlinks"/"Confirmconsentlink" command

But that will prompt a login window which then filters out to get the authorization code.
I figured it would be possible to do this with an AD token, but i'm not sure to pass it correctly to the parameters of the Invoke command, to authorize it correctly.

Does anyone know how to confirm the consent link using an AD token? or obtain the authorization code, using an SPN?

Answer (score 0):

The API connections `office365`, `dropbox`, `dynamicscrmonline`, etc, are all need a user-interaction, it uses the [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to authorize, so it will prompt a login window.
 I don't think you can use only a SPN to authorize, if you just use a SPN, you could just use the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow), that is not supported by the API connections.